# command.com vs cmd.exe

Tags: command-line

What are the operations that are possible in command.com but not supported in cmd.exe and vice-versa?

These pages give a beginners description: [command.com vs cmd.exe](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000395.htm) and [What's the difference between COMMAND.COM and CMD.EXE?](http://ask-leo.com/whats_the_difference_between_commandcom_and_cmdexe.html)

However, I am looking for some practical situations where it is more appropriate (or correct) to use command.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On machines where there still *is* a `command.com` this is run by the [NTVDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTVDM). The version included in those systems is—to my knowledge—identical with DOS 6.2 and can therefore be used to run batch files that expect such a system.

For all practical purposes however, you can just use `cmd.exe` as its commands are (mostly) a super-set of `command.com`'s.

Contrary to Alex' answer, you don't need to run 16-bit programs from `command.com`. Windows takes care of starting such programs in the NTDVM itself.

As for the commands available in either shell, you can take a look [here](http://robvanderwoude.com/batchcommands.php) which has four columns referring to availability in DOS and Windows.

Comment: Actually, it's a lot closer to DOS 7. (Betcha never heard of that before!)

Answer (score 4):

use CMD.EXE to run batch scripts or other interactive terminal operations, such as getting network diagnostics or manually configuring mount-points.

use COMMAND.COM to run *legacy* DOS programs, such as old games or accounting packages, since it simulates the operation of an ancient DOS computer.

COMMAND.COM can also run batch scripts etc, but has an older, more limited interface which will make it more difficult.  It may also consume more memory and CPU resources to do the same task, since it has all the overhead of simulating the ancient DOS computer, which CMD does not.

Comment: You don't need to run `command.com` just for executing other programs. Legacy batch files yes, programs definitely not. It's not as if `command.com` was a magic gateway into the 16-bit world. It's just another 16-bit application.